# phpseclib new NET_SSH2 does not work

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload, phpseclib, spl-autoload-register

i want to use the phpseclib in my project. If I test it in a single way, it works all fine. But when i put it in my sourcecode the sreen is blank.

Here is the part of the code:

```
<?php
namespace data;

spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
spl_autoload_register();

session_start();

//set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');

require '/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php';
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('localhost'); // this will not work?

?>
```

I work with namespace. When i load SSH2.php with require it works all fine. But at the point i open it with `$ssh = new Net_SSH2('localhost');`the code crashed and the screen is blank.

Currently i got the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Class
>   Math_BigInteger could not be loaded' in
>   /var/www/test/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php:857 Stack trace: #0 [internal
>   function]: spl_autoload('Math_BigInteger') #1
>   /var/www/test/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php(857):
>   class_exists('Math_BigInteger') #2 /var/www/test/index.php(15):
>   Net_SSH2->Net_SSH2('localhost') #3 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/test/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php on line 857

This is the actually code:

```
namespace data;

error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set("display_errors", 1);

spl_autoload_extensions('.php');

spl_autoload_register();

session_start();

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib'); 

require 'phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php';

$ssh = new \Net_SSH2('localhost');
```

Comment: You're using PHP's built-in default autoloader so it's trying to load a file called Math_BigInteger.php in the phpseclib/Net/ directory. To do autoloading with phpseclib 0.3 / 1.0 you'll need to use a PSR-0 autoloader. eg. http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/

Answer (score 0):

The screen is probably blank because you have display_errors set to 1. If you do `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your PHP file you'll probably start seeing errors.

In lieu of knowing what errors you're getting I'd wager to guess that you need to do `\Net_SSH2` instead of `Net_SSH2`.